# Dovecot-mysql has unresolved dependancies

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I have set up a new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server with a LAMP + Postfix + Dovecot setup. Almost everything is working but I am getting an issue with dovecot dependencies. I have installed dovecot-core using `apt install dovecot-core` but when I try to add dovecot-mysql `apt install dovecot-mysql' I get the below error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dovecot-mysql : Depends: dovecot-core (= 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2) but 1:2.2.33.2-1ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I get the identical error with dovecot-lmtpd

What is the best way of resolving this? I can download binaries of older versions of the dovecot components and install them manually but I am unsure if this is the best method.

Comment: 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2 is from Xenial (16.04) while 1:2.2.33.2-1ubuntu4.1 is from Bionic-updates (18.04). Looks like you caused the Impossible Situation by trying to add 16.04 package (from a 16.04 source) to an 18.04 system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It has helped me get this resolved. I had a Xenial repo in my list. I removed the repo and dovecot-mysql was then unavailable (At this time it is not in the Bionic repo). I added the repo from Dovecot - https://repo.dovecot.org/ - and it is all good now. I would have marked you as the answer but it was only a comment.